# Is it possible toaccess Hive data in Hadoop HDInsight cluster using R?

Tags: r, azure, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to access Hive data in Hadoop HDInsight cluster using R? Say we don't have R Server, all I am interested in is by using R as a client tool accessing Hive data?

Comment: It should be, with the `RJDBC` package, and the Hive drivers accessible locally as Java jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for accessing Hive without R Server. There are many solutions for doing this, as below.

1. [RHive](https://github.com/nexr/RHive), an R extension facilitating distributed computing via Apache Hive. There is a [slide](https://www.slideshare.net/miloveme/r-hive-introduction) you can refer to, but it seems to be too old and not support YARN.
2. [RJDBC](http://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/), a package implementing DBI in R on the basis of JDBC. There is a [blog](http://a%20package%20implementing%20DBI%20in%20R%20on%20the%20basis%20of%20JDBC.) which introduce the usage for R with Hive.
3. [R package `hive`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hive/hive.pdf), there is the document for this package, you can refer to and know how to use it.

It seems that the R package `hive` is a good choice, because it support the version of Hadoop is `Apache Hadoop >= 2.6.0` that HDInsight based on it.

Hope it helps.